# SerialPort.Write() method is hanging

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm quite new with serial ports. And I'm trying to write some data to serial ports created by this tool called com0com. But like the title says, it hangs when it tries to write (both Write() & WriteLine()) to the serial port (opening and closing the port is working though). I can also find the port in the Device Manger.

I tried with different baud rates, but it is still hanging. I also delayed the execution for 1 seconds before writing to the port but this didn't work either.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM15", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
mySerialPort.Open();
try
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   mySerialPort.WriteLine("p");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw;
}
finally
{
   mySerialPort.Close();
}
```

The exception was not thrown at all. It just hangs at `mySerialPort.WriteLine("p");`. I've been trying to solve this for days. I would be really appreciated if you could point me out what I've been missing here. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that another process is reading from that com port?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Oops. I didn't know that the code continues when you try to read. And here I was thinking that the code is hanging. Thank you for pointing me out.

Comment: The server (device) is not recognizing the message you are sending.  The data rate could be wrong, the message could be invalid, the server may need a different end of line that the one you are sending.  Every device is different and without see the manual I cannot tell what is wrong.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the comment. Actually, I got it working now. Like Matthew said, all I had to do was read from another process. It's like ```mySerialPort.WriteLine("p");``` is waiting someone to read before moving on.

Comment: You were closing the connection in the finally so you were never receiving the response.